# Ignore accented chars Eloquent query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, character-encoding, eloquent

I'm trying to query registers with fields that can contain accents like `à á ä` (Catalan language). When I search **'alex'** it does not returns **'Àlex'** register.

I'm using `laravel 5.5`, `mysql 5.7` and `PHP 7.0`.

Search code:

```
$client = new Client();
$client = $client->newQuery();

if ($request->has('name') && !empty($name = $request->input('name'))) 
{
    $client->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$name%");
}

return $client->get();
```

How can I query registers without distinguishing accents and case of the chars using Eloquent and Laravel?

Comment: so do you want to treat accented chatacters same as normal ones?

Comment: @SapneshNaik Yes, without distinguishing them

Comment: Best solution I think would be to use an already built solution since it's a little bit ungrateful to use a custom solution, you can consider https://github.com/TomLingham/Laravel-Searchy#unicode-characters-support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the configuration of test. I was using **sqlite** instead of mysql. Thanks for the answers. The default configuration of laravel for mysql works:

**`config/database.php`**

```
'mysql' => [
    ...
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 1):

To have an accent insensitive search you can change the `collation` at runtime in the raw sql query,

**Try:**

```
$client->whereRaw("name like  '%$name%' collate utf8_general_ci ");
```

Answer (score 0):

`SHOW CREATE TABLE`. You will probably find that `COLLATION ..._bin`.  Change "bin" to "general_ci" so that accent stripping and case folding will be done during searching and sorting.